# How to get all fields of tables related through a foreign key as well as a many to many relationship in django ORM?

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, many-to-many, django-select-related

I have a table **User_Device** with fields *username*, *num_of_years* and *device* (foreign key), table **Device** with fields *id*, *name*, *type* and *many to many relationship* on field *property*, which is the third table **Property** that has fields *id*, *name*, *location*. I know how to get all the fields from the first 2 tables:

```
User_Device.objects.select_related('device').all()
```

I also know how to get all the fields of the many to many table:

```
Device.property.through.objects.all()
```

or filter using:

```
Device.property.through.objects.filter(property=12)
```

which gives me all the fields of the many to many table alone, which looks like **Device_Property** with fields *device_id*, *property_id*

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get all fields of the Device table and the property table like the SQL query would give when you inner join it like:
   `select d.*,p.* from device_property dp inner join property p on dp.property_id=p.id inner join device d on dp.device_id=d.id`
2. How to inner join all the three tables and get all fields like the result of the query:

   `select ud.*,d.*,p.* from user_device ud inner join device_property dp on ud.device_id = dp.device_id inner join property p on dp.property_id=p.id inner join device d on dp.device_id=d.id`

**In conclusion table A has a foreign key field on table B and table B has a many to many relationship with table C (NOT foreign key). How do I get ALL fields of table A, B, C**

Comment: Please do *not* think in terms of *tables* but in terms of *models*. The second query is not a good idea, since it *repeats* the data for the `device` and `device_property` recods, and thus will result in a *massive* amount of data hat contains a *huge* amount of duplicates. In order to fetch a one-to-many or many-to-many, you use a `.prefetch_related`, which will make one query to then fetch the related objects, and do the joining at the Python/Django layer.

Comment: I tried using prefetch related but it wasn't selecting any of the columns of the many_to_many related model

Comment: @HyungaHInata: exactly, and that is because of the reason stated above: it could simply result in a huge amount of bandwidth used to repeat the same data again and again. `.prefetch_related` makes a second query, but results in limited bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the negatives of doing that, but just for the purpose of understanding Django better, IS there a way I could technically get all columns of all these 3 tables?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem stated above, please help me also @HyugaHinata

Comment: @vikash I don't think I got around to finding out how to achieve this the "right" way. I suppose you can always write raw SQL to achieve this or write a nested ORM query. I don't remember what happens if you try to explicitly specify the columns you want using `.values_list()` Maybe you could try that?